# Getting selected value from combobox returns null javafx

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to set and get the selected value from the the combobox (which is populated by enums) but when I try selecting an item from the combobox then printing out getSelected it returns null?

Comment: Likely, the downvote was posted at the same time as the close vote, which has a reason (you can see when clicking on the close link) of “needs detail clarity”. For a question like this sometimes that can be added via a [mcve], though, in this case, it turned out to be answerable without additional detail supplied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is that the following line prints `null`?

```
System.out.println(getType()); //test
```

This is because

1. the value of `type` is not set yet
2. by default, the selected item of comboBox is null. You can set it with `comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0) //or whatever value`